# Reverse a string in Python but dont reverse alphanumerics

Tags: python

I want to reveres a string but not alphanumeric characters and spaces in it. How we can achieve it?

```
input : "This is Testing! The email-id is testing@my.com"
output : "sihT si gnitseT! ehT di-liame si gnitset@ym.moc"
```

how can I achieve it without re?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `re` module here? That's not why regexes are there.

Comment: then how can I achieve it? I dont mind using plain python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Through `re.sub`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is Testing! The email is testing@my.com"
>>> re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m: m.group()[::-1], s)
'sihT si gnitseT! ehT liame si gnitset@ym.moc'
```

We all know that `\w+` matches one or more word characters. And note that we also use an anonymous function as second parameter in the `re.sub` function which in-turn helps to do string operations on the matched characters.

Comment: can you tell me how can we do this without re module

Comment: you are asking `Reverse a string in Python with re module`

Comment: yes Borja but if I can get idea how to do it without re, will be in good knowledge for me

Comment: The problem with the question is that you were first asking for a solution with `re` and now you are asking a solution without `re` this can be a bit messy for users looking for answers.

Comment: @Avinash Raj: there is only one change and near reversing the email-id

Comment: yes. It will be great to know how to use hyphen as well in it. because if user will enter email-id instead of email, answer will be wrong.

Comment: `re.sub(r'[-\w]+', lambda m: m.group()[::-1], "This is Testing! The email-id is testing@my.com")`

Comment: its not matching the answer Avinash. in email-id, reverse should be di-liame

Comment: Thanks. yes I got the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
text = "This is Testing! The email-id is testing@my.com"
reversed_text = " ".join(text[::-1].split()[::-1])
```

'sihT si !gnitseT ehT di-liame si moc.ym@gnitset'

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output.